# How to increase the expiry time of a firebase auth token, I don't want to use firebase client, is there a way to do something only at the backend

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, access-token

I made my custom backend with nodejs using firebase cloud functions and the auth token expiry time is only 1 hour for the admin sdk how to increase the expiry time of token or something to counter this issue without using the firebase-client in my web app

Answer (score 0):

If you're [creating custom tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_a_third-party_jwt_library) you're bound by this requirement that Firebase places on the `exp` claim:

> `exp`:    Expiration time
>
> The time, in seconds since the UNIX epoch, at which the token expires. It can be a maximum of 3600 seconds later than the iat.

You might want to look into [session cookies](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies), which (according to the documentation) allow:

> Ability to create session cookies with custom expiration times ranging from 5 minutes to 2 weeks.